# Linear Ticks on a log plot in R's GGplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In R, is there any way to have linear tickmarks on a plot with logarithmic axes? I'm plotting a bunch of log-log regressions on a scatter plot, but I want the final axes to be linear in scale. Therefore I'm starting with log data, plotting a bunch of regressions, and using "coord_trans(x="exp", y="exp")" to get the data plotted in a linear space. However, the axes still have log scales on them. Is there any way to get the axes to have linear scale as well?

Here's my code:

```
ggplot(oj,aes(x=logprice,y=logmove, color = factor(brand))) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(se=F, method=lm, colour="black") +
  geom_smooth(aes(dtimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="red", data=dft) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(mmtimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="green", data=mmft) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ttimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="blue", data=tropft) +
  geom_smooth(aes(dtimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="red", data=dnft, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(mmtimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="green", data=mmnft, linetype = "dashed") + 
  geom_smooth(aes(ttimeslp,logmove), method=lm, se=F, colour="blue", data=tropnft, linetype = "dashed") +
  xlab("Log(price)") + ylab("Log(sales)") + coord_trans(x="exp", y="exp")
```

And a picture:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some data from your dataset? Or sample data that has the same issue? That way we can play around with it and ensure our solutions work before answering your question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, you should work with untransformed x and y aesthetics.  Transform x and y via the appropriate `scale` function, like `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log")` (you'll likely need to set your breaks).  Then you can use `coord_trans` to put plot back on original scale.