# ggplot: Log scale with linear labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wish to log transform my data but have an axis with linear values that correspond to the log ticks. For example, in page 3 of the following PDF from Iversen and Soskice 2002. The data has been transformed, but the labels are in their corresponding linear values for readability.

http://faculty.washington.edu/cadolph/vis/vishw1.pdf

Here is some reproducible data and my start to the plot:

```
set.seed(51)
data<-data.frame(country=letters[1:14], 
                 poverty=runif(14,min=1,max=100),
                 parties=runif(14,min=1,max=10))

ggplot(data, aes(parties, poverty))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_x_log10()
```

Any ideas? I have seen other similar questions but none of them have working answers (e.g. [Linear Ticks on a log plot in R's GGplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935005/linear-ticks-on-a-log-plot-in-rs-ggplot)).

Comment: the example could be made more minimal, and especially, more illustrative simulating data from skewed/log-normal distribution rather than uniform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `trans` inside `scale_x_contineous`, which transform axis only.

```
ggplot(data, aes(parties, poverty))+
    geom_point(size=2)+
    scale_x_continuous(
        trans = "log10",
        breaks = 1:10
    )
```

Comment: The only difference between your graph and the OP's is the `breaks = 1:10`.  Switching to `scale_x_continuous` with `trans` has no difference compared to `scale_x_log10`

Answer (score 8):

`coord_trans` does exactly that:

```
ggplot(data, aes(parties, poverty))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  coord_trans(x = 'log10')
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to the other two answers, but gives you something a little different:

```
ggplot(data, aes(parties, poverty))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  scale_x_log10(breaks = scales::log_breaks(n = 10)) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "b")
```

if you want it on both the x and y axis then you need to add:

```
 scale_y_log10(breaks = scales::log_breaks(n = 10))
```

and change `sides = "b"` to `sides = "bl"` in the `annotation_logticks()` function.

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `breaks` parameter covers (checkout `?scale_x_log10`).

For your current question, you could modify the last line to:

```
scale_x_log10(breaks = 1:999)
```

or

```
scale_x_log10(breaks = 2*(1:999))  # just even numbers
```

etc.